# What is it called when sound from next scene begins before the current scene is over?

Tags: terminology, editing

Sometimes, in films the sound for the next scene will begin while the current scene is still playing.

For example, in Episode 3 of Season 5 of Game of Thrones, Arya is washing a corpse for the first time with the Waif and the viewer hears a man shout "Open the gate!" and a second later the scene switches to Petyr Baelish and his entourage escorting Sansa Stark through the gates of Winterfell. So, basically the sound switches over before the scene does.

What is the name for this kind of transition effect?

Comment: It's called prelap. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Prelap